# Nginx pod is not connecting to internet

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, kubernetes, networking

I have install kubeadm in master and connected 2 worker node to it, after that i deploy nginx pod and ssh into that nginx pod after that i type nslookup google.com or apt update its not working got connection timeout it think due its not connecting to internet.  How to solve it, The 3 VM is running in azure portal and 3 VM are connected to together. kubectl v1.24.2 im using it

The 3 VM is running in azure portal and 3 VM are connected to together. kubectl v1.24.2 im using it and calico network also im using

[image]

nginx pod is running in worker2 and services of containerd container runtime/Docker Application Container Engine both are in running state. if i type lsmod | grep br_netfilter i got

```
br_netfilter           28672  0
bridge                266240  1 br_netfilter
```

here is my nginx.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
#          command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
#          args: ["apt update"]
#          securityContext:
#            privileged: true               


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
   app: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      name: nginx-http
```

And Here is the screenshot of coredns install in kube-system naming space
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like name is not resolving, please check if coredns is working properly. You can break down the issue like this:

- from inside the pod first check you have network reachability to the internet: curl -v telnet://8.8.8.8:53
- check you have connectivity to core DNS: curl -v telnet://coredns_service_name:53 or curl -v telnet://coredns_cluster_ip:53

Comment: i have added screenshot of coredns its running
I have test 1st one and return with connected to 8.8.8.8
2nd its not working got failed to connect to coredns ip or service name

Below is the coredns 2nd command output and 172.16.237.1 is the coredns pod IP
curl -v telnet://172.16.237.1:53
*   Trying 172.16.237.1:53...
* connect to 172.16.237.1 port 53 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 172.16.237.1 port 53: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.16.237.1 port 53: Connection timed out

Comment: It seems that the caliconode is not running properly, please check and fix the calico issue

Comment: caliaco node is working i check logs